# How to model shocks to parameter in a dynamic system?

Tags: functions

My simple model is:

```
m[t_] := m[t] = m[t - 1]*p + 2
m[0] = 0
p = 0.5
```

I can plot the system as:

```
DiscretePlot[m[t], {t, 0, 50}]
```

Now, I would like to shock `p` for a short period, say, from 10 to 13 during which it would be 0.8 and then recovering its original value, 0.5, afterwards. Would `Insert` do this?

Comment: I would guess something like `p[t_] /; 10 <= t <= 13 := 0.8; p[_] := 0.5`.  And use `p[t]` instead of `p` in your definition of `m`.  But I don't understand the mathematical model.  Could you explain it?

Comment: @MichaelE2, thanks so much, I solved it!

Answer (score 10):

No, `Insert` wouldn't work in your case because `m[t]` isn't a `List`. In your recursive definition, the "shock" can be incorporated directly as follows:

```
Clear[m]; 
m[t_] := m[t] = m[t - 1]*Piecewise[{{q, 10 <= t <= 13}, {p, True}}] + 2
m[0] = 0;
p = 0.5;
q = 0.8;

DiscretePlot[m[t], {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: DiscretePlot]

What I did is use [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html) to decide whether to apply the factor `p` or `q`.

Comment: Or just `If[10 <= t <= 13,q, p]` instead of `Piecewise[{{q, 10 <= t <= 13}, {p, True}}]`

Comment: @Murta and Jens, thanks so much, it works!!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `Piecewise`, you could construct a separate function for `p` using [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnitStep.html?q=UnitStep&lang=en). The modularity might provide more flexibility.

```
p[t_, shockAmplitudeDelta_, tBeginShock_, tEndShock_] := 0.5 + shockAmplitudeDelta(UnitStep[t - tBeginShock] - 
 UnitStep[t - tEndShock])
m[t_] := m[t] = m[t - 1]*p[t, 0.3, 10, 13] + 2
m[0] = 0;
DiscretePlot[m[t], {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> {0, 8}]
```

This provides the same `DiscretePlot` as Jens produced:

[image]

Comment: this is great! I'll try right away! Thanks so much!