# How to plot particular piecewise defined functions in mathematica

Tags: plotting, recursion

How to plot such functions in *Mathematica*?

Let $a_0, p,g,c$ be any positive integers, defining:

$$a_{n+1} = \begin{cases}\frac{a_n}{p} &, a_n \text{ divisible by p}\\ ga_n +c &, a_n \text{ odd}. \end{cases}$$

PS I am new to *Mathematica*, I am really sorry if my ignorance is borderline offensive.

Comment: Take a look at [`f[x_] := f[x] = ...`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/5478) too.

Comment: Be aware of the fact that what you presented is a sequence not a function. You could of course define a piecewise constant function which takes the values of a_n, or do a ListPlot (see answer below).

Comment: Tom, welcome to mathematica.stackexchange.com! In future questions, please try to show/explain what you have tried yourself. Maybe you tried to plot a discrete function with `Plot` and it didn't work. That kind of information sometimes doesn't make the question any clearer (most of the time showing us your code helps a lot), but in any case it shows us your effort. I like that you formatted your question though, so I'd say this is a pretty nice first question.

Comment: Related: [How to model shocks to parameter in a dynamic system?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44091/4330)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite strightforward;

```
a[n_, p_: 3, g_: 2, c_: 1] := a[n] = If[Divisible[a[n - 1], p], 
                                        a[n - 1]/p, 
                                        g a[n - 1] + c]

Manipulate[
 a[0] = a0;
 DiscretePlot[a[x, p, g, c], {x, 1, 50}, BaseStyle -> {Bold, 18}],
 {{p, 3}, 2, 10, 1},
 {{g, 1}, 0, 10, 1},
 {{c, 1}, 0, 10, 1},
 {{a0, 2}, 1, 10, 1},
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: Notice that there is a silent assumption that we know `DiscretePlot` will plot points in order. It is important because if for example it starts from `x=50` then after switching `a0` it will refer to `a[49]` which was calculated for previous `a0`. But it's not the case so don't worry :)